# Different Form login in Shiro

Tags: java, security, shiro

Same question where asked under "Multiple logins url in Shiro" but it was unanswered.

I am trying to have two different loggin page for apache shiro
1) For Mobile devices (little screen, limited javascript different theme)
2) For standard devices

How can i do?

Now only one url is working at a time.

shiro.loginUrl = ...

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend `FormAuthenticationFilter` to be aware of multiple login urls. It can look like this:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends FormAuthenticationFilter {
    private Map<String, String> loginUrlByUserAgent = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void setLoginUrls(final Map<String, String> loginUrlByUserAgent) {
        this.loginUrlByUserAgent = loginUrlByUserAgent;
    }

    protected void redirectToLogin(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        final String loginUrl = getLoginUrl(request);
        WebUtils.issueRedirect(request, response, loginUrl);
    }

    private String getLoginUrl(final ServletRequest request) {
        // check user agent
        final String userAgent = getUserAgent(request);
        // and return appropriate login url
        return userAgent != null && loginUrlByUserAgent.containsKey(userAgent) ?
                loginUrlByUserAgent.get(userAgent) :
                getLoginUrl();
    }

    private String getUserAgent(final ServletRequest request) {
        // get "User-Agent" header
    }
}
```

Then you just need to replace authc filter with your newly created.